# Unable to perform ajax post operation

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

[image]I have the following json data:

```
[
  {
    "Password": "tedd",
    "Username": "john",
    "status": true
  }
]
```

which i want to consume using post method

```
<label for="Username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="txtUserName" placeholder="Enter UserName"/>
<label for="Password">Password</label>
<input type="text" id="txtPass" placeholder="Enter Password" />
<input type="button" onclick="loginc()" value="Click Me" />
```

app logic:

```
function loginc() {   
var username = document.getElementById("txtUserName").value;
if (username == "") {
    alert("Please enter the valid name");
    return false;
}

var password = document.getElementById("txtPass").value;
if (password == "") {
    alert("Please enter valid password");
}
var urlink = "http://192.168.0.112/Service1.svc/getlogin";

var datat = { Username: "username", Password: "password" };



$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: urlink,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",

    data:datat,

    success: function (resp) {                
        alert(resp);
        if (resp.length != 0) {
            alert("Logged On");
        } else {
            alert("Wrong Credentials");
        }

    },
    error: function (e) {

        alert("Invalid");

    }
});
```

So here the problem is when ever i enter username and password, click on the button instead of validating i am not getting any response and it is displaying wrong credentials in the error.

[image: This is the result im getting in the post man]

Comment: If you get `"Wrong Credentials"` you're getting a response, it's just empty, meaning the error is most likely serverside?

Comment: @Madpop   replace `alert("Invalid")` with `alert(e.responseText)` and check the exact error, then you will come to know where you are doing wrong.

Comment: @Krish actually replaced it what u said and i didn't get any responsetext

Comment: @adeneo Actually i checked url with postman and i got the data successfully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to append parameters to `url`.

```
var datat = { Username: username, Password: password };

$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: urlink+'?username='+username+'&password='+password,
   dataType: "json",
   contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
   data:datat,
   success: function (resp) {                
      alert(resp);
      if (resp.length != 0) {
        alert("Logged On");
      } else {
        alert("Wrong Credentials");
      }

   },
   error: function (e) {
      alert("Invalid");
   }
});
```

Another solution is to send the object using `JSON.stringify()` method.

`contentType` is the type of data you're sending, so you need `application/json;` The default is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8.`

If you use `application/json`, you have to use `JSON.stringify()` in order to send `JSON` object.

`JSON.stringify()` turns a `javascript` object to json text and stores it in a string.

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: urlink,
   dataType: "json",
   contentType: "application/json",
   data:JSON.stringify(datat),
   success: function (resp) {                
      alert(resp);
      if (resp.length != 0) {
        alert("Logged On");
      } else {
        alert("Wrong Credentials");
      }

   },
   error: function (e) {
      alert("Invalid");
   }
});
```

Comment: Nope no result same like image

Comment: I think the error is from server-side, because you received empty response.

Comment: @ Alexandru-Ionut Mihai please check the image of the post man

Comment: @Madpop, have a look to my answer.

Comment: Working man now got result in alert.

Comment: But my doubt is by using the data also we can do that right . but why it is not working

Comment: Try to use `data:JSON.stringify(datat)` and `contentType:'application/json'`

Answer (score 3):

```
var datat = { Username: "username", Password: "password" };
```

Here, you are sending the literal string `username` and `password` instead of the variables. Remove the quotes:

```
var datat = { Username: username, Password: password };
```

Comment: _*Facedesk*_. I guess we better close this as "Typo".

Comment: Nope same  didn't get any response, Please check my post for image